# Remove Lines less than 3 words in a Text File

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, sed

I have seen commands such as using sed to remove lines based on number of characters but not words.

eg. I have a text file such as

```
word1
word1 word2
word1 word2 word3
word1 word2 word3 word4
word1 word2 word4 word5
```

How would i use (sed or awk) to remove the lines with less than 3 words so output looks like:

```
word1 word2 word3
word1 word2 word3 word4
word1 word2 word4 word5
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this simply in awk,

```
$ awk 'NF>=3' file
word1 word2 word3
word1 word2 word3 word4
word1 word2 word4 word5
```

It prints the lines which has three or more fields.

Comment: WOWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW

Comment: Why a long wow? You can express your feelings by upvoting :-)

Comment: Similar answer at same time

Comment: Cool as simple! Thanks ;d

Answer (score 4):

Here is how to do it with `awk`, If its more than `2` fields, print it:

```
awk 'NF>2' file
word1 word2 word3
word1 word2 word3 word4
word1 word2 word4 word5
```

Comment: WOWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW

Comment: Cool as simple! Thanks ;d

Answer (score 1):

You can try is `sed` command

```
sed -n 's/\([^ ]\+ \)\{2,\}/&/p' file_name

[^ ] - until space match each characters
{2,} - which is used to match the preceding pattern more than 2
([^ ]\+ ) - Which is used to match the word.
```

Comment: You could simply use this `sed -n '/\([^ ]* \)\{2,\}/p' file`

Comment: ([^ ]* ) - Which is used to match the at least 1 space with eventually a non space so no word match also. ([^ ]+ ) - match a word. (assuming there is only space and alpha numeric values like in sample)

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n '/[^ ]\([^ ]*  *[^ ]\)\{2\}/ p' YourFile
# or
sed -n '/[^ ]  *[^ ][^ ]*  *[^ ]/ p' YourFile
```

Regx is: At least 1 non space with at least 1 space with at least 1 non space with at least 1 space with at least 1 non space

to ensure that (`word1 word2`) is not taking sourround space as word separator with no word to separe at the extremities

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n 's/\<//3p' file
```